# homomorphism from group G to group H

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let f be a homomorphism from group G to group H, K be the kernel of f, which of the following statement is right?
I.K is a normal subgroup in G
II. f(G) is a normal subgroup in H
III. G/K is isomorphic to a subgroup in H

Comment: Have you learned any theorems about group homomorphisms that might shed light on (or immediately answer) your questions? If not, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

I. K is a normal subgroup in G. Let $g\in K$ and $a,a^{-1}\in G$ then

$f(aga^-1)=f(a)f(g)f(a^-1)=f(a)ef(a)^-1=e$.

III. $G/K$ is isomorphic to the image $f(G)$ (by the 1st isomorphism theorem) Of course $f(G)$ is a subgroup of H thus $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of H.

About II. Suppose $b=f(g)$ for some $g\in G$ and $h,h^-1\in H$.

$hbh^-1$ may not always belong to $f(G)$ so $f(G)$ is not always a normal subgroup of H.

Answer (score 1):

I.$K$ is a normal subgroup in $G$

III. $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup in $H$